# Combat game - character factory

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, role-playing-game, abstract-factory

I decided to improve my OOP design knowledge and learn python at the same time so I started to write a simple program which will be a fight "simulator".

For now, there are only 2 character types : Orc and Human.
The `CharacterFactory` class is created so that I'll be able to handle `Orc` and `Human` classes in a more abstract way or so.

`GameState` is meant to track the state of the game. Instances will be immediately registered to the `GameState` as soon as they created. And for example, if a character dies, I want to remove it from the list as well. (`self.characters`).

```
    #abtract factory or something 
class CharacterFactory:
    def __init__(self, character=None, game_state=None):
        self.character = character
        game_state.register_character(self)

    def inspect(self):
        print(self.character.name)
        print(self.character.attack_dmg)
        print(self.character.health)
        print("\n")

    def attack(self, target):
        target.character.health = target.character.health - self.character.attack_dmg

#Observable or so
class GameState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.characters = []

    def register_character(self, character):
        self.characters.append(character)

    def show_characters(self):
        list(map(lambda x: x.inspect(), self.characters))


class Orc:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.attack_dmg = 50
        self.health = 100

class Human:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.attack_dmg = 45
        self.health = 105

def Main():
    game_state = GameState()

    orc = CharacterFactory(Orc("Karcsi"),game_state)
    #orc.inspect()
    #orc.attack()


    human = CharacterFactory(Human("Nojbejtoo"),game_state)
    #human.inspect()
    #human.attack()

    print("Game state:\n")

    game_state.show_characters()

    orc.attack(human)

    game_state.show_characters()

Main()
```

My question is:

Is this a good design? Or maybe a complete pain in the ... to work with? Is there something that I could improve?

Of course this code is really far from being finished, but I try to find the best approach possible to design things like this so that i can deepen my knowledge in design patterns and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The CharacterFactory class is created so that I'll be able to handle Orc and Human classes in a more abstract way or so.

You try to stay DRY which is very good, but this idea would be better represented with [inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php).

You could create a `class Character()` and let both `Human` and `Orc`, inherit from the super class like so:

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, health, attack_damage, name):
        self.attack_damage = attack_damage
        self.health = health
        self.name = name

    def attack(self, target):
        target.health -= self.attack_damage

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}\nDamage: {self.attack_damage}\nHealth: {self.health}\n"

class Human(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, health=105, attack_damage=45):
        super().__init__(health, attack_damage, name)

class Orc(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, health=100, attack_damage=50):
        super().__init__(health, attack_damage, name)

def main():
    orc = Orc("Karcsi")
    human = Human("Nojbejtoo")

    print(orc)
    print(human)

    orc.attack(human)
    print(human)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Things I changed:

- Instead of an inspect function, I override the magic function `__str__` so you can directly `print(human)` or `print(orc)`
- The use of the `if __name__ == '__main__'`
- And the `snake_case` functions `main` instead of `Main`
- In the `attack` function body, see how `a = a - b` equals `a -= b`

I have omitted the `GameState` part, maybe someone else will pick that up.

Good luck with your game!

Comment: Okay, then I'll go with inheritance instead. Thank you for the hints :) !